# Python, sqlite3: data format for inserting multiple values?

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I have some difficulties to come up with proper title for my problem.

I’m trying to learn a little bit about SQLite and database and I came up with little exercise (I’m aware that for this specific case making multiple tables doesn’t make much sense, it’s all just for exercise and finding out ‘how-to’). 
The database is supposed to contain a few tables: main “movies table”, “year table”, “director table” and “category table”.
[Picture for easier understanding.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgqmo.png)

After creating tables, I wanted to populate them with tuple of tuples. I have no problem with “little” tables for example, populating directors table.

```
    Dir = ((0, ‘Blip’), (1, ‘Blop’), (2, ‘Blap’))
```

then:

```
with con:
    cur = con.cursor()    

    cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Directors")
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Directors(Id INT PRIMARY KEY, Director TEXT)")
    cur.executemany("INSERT INTO Directors VALUES(?, ?, ?)", Dir)
```

The problem appears with main movie table. How to pass multitude category values for each movie? Should I pass this collection of values as another tuple?

```
Movies = ((‘Dog’, 0, 0, 1), (‘Cat’, 0, 0, (1, 2)), 
         (‘Ant’, 1, 1, (0, 2)), (‘Crow’, 2, 2, (0, 1, 2)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another table. This is a many-to-many relationship, and as such needs a through table with foreign keys to both Movies and Categories. Then you can insert one row for each pair of (movie, category): so:

```
Dog, 1
Cat, 1
Cat, 2
Ant, 0
Ant, 2
etc.
```

(Also, it's good practice to have a primary key for each table: for movies, you might want to use an autoincrement integer field rather than the title.)